# Nesting columns under new headers in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
stocks= ['Apple','Raytheon','Amazon'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[10,11,12,13,5,2],[5,6,7,7,7,1]],
                        columns=['2020-12-31','2019-12-31','2020-09-26','2019-09-28','2020-01-01','2019-01-01'], index=['cash','inventory'])
```

I have this list of stocks and their balance sheets in a dataframe. I would like to group the first 2 columns(2020-12-31,2019-12-31) under Apple, the next two columns under Raytheon and the last two under Amazon.

How to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scaling the `stocks` list up with [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy-repeat) then `zip` and use [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas-multiindex-from-tuples):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(np.repeat(stocks, 2), df.columns))
```

`df`:

```
               Apple              Raytheon                Amazon           
          2020-12-31 2019-12-31 2020-09-26 2019-09-28 2020-01-01 2019-01-01
cash              10         11         12         13          5          2
inventory          5          6          7          7          7          1
```